# Meteor upsert equivalent

Tags: mongodb, meteor, upsert

How soon will the upsert command be implemented in Meteor?

And, what is the best way to do the same thing in the mean time?

Something like this is what I'm doing at the moment:

```
if typeof ( item = Items.findOne({title:'Foo'}) ) == 'undefined'
    item = Items.insert({title:'Foo'})
else
    Items.update(item._id, {$set: {title:'Foo'}})
# do something with item
```

Comment: With your solution, note that if two separate clients execute the findOne() at the same time, then two documents with `{title:'Foo'}` will be created.

Comment: True, then a meteor implementation of upsert would be ideal. Since if two clients run upsert with the same data, they create individual documents on their client simulated db; then meteor would sync the two documents when they run on the server. It might get a bit hairy, though... I can see why it isn't implemented yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How soon will the upsert command be implemented in Meteor?

UPDATE: [@Thomas4019](https://stackoverflow.com/users/360051/thomas4019) points out that `upsert` is now supported:

v0.6.6

"Add upsert support. Collection.update now supports the {upsert: true} option. Additionally, add a Collection.upsert method which returns the newly inserted object id if applicable."

Source: [History.md](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#mongodb)

Usage documentation: http://docs.meteor.com/#upsert

-- original answer follows --

There is a card on the Trello Meteor Roadmap which you can vote on to indicate its importance to you: https://trello.com/c/C91INHmj

It is currently in the "Later" list which means it will be a while before it is implemented unless it receives a lot of votes.

The other important thing to note is that since meteor is open-source, you could implement the necessary changes yourself and submit back.

---

> What is the best way to do the same thing in the mean time?

There are several solutions but which is most appropriate for your use-case is impossible to tell without more knowledge of your design.

1. Use the code as is, add an unique index to the collection, and handle the duplicate key error if/when it arises
2. Change design to implement explicit optimistic concurrency.

The core of both of these solutions is the same, gracefully handle the error case.  #1 is easier to implement.  #2 allows for greater flexibility in how the optimistic concurrency is handled.

Comment: Upsert functionality is now built-in.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do that, you can use the mongodb connection directly: `MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db.collection('myCollection').update(query, update, {upsert: true})`. Of course this connection is not documented so there is a chance that it can be changed in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Upsert is really easy with this trick.  you just check if it has an `_id` property:

```
if(item._id){
  //update
}else{
  //insert
}
```