# Is it possible check if a field exists in a meteor collection if not add it?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In a Meteor Mongo Collection, is it possible that we check if a field exists and if not not, add that field ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meteor upsert equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206015/meteor-upsert-equivalent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You need to use the `$exists` operator in your Mongo query. For example with a collection called `Posts`:

```
Posts.update({
    _id: 'abcdef123',
    myField: {
        $exists: false
    }
}, {
    $set: {
        myField: 'myValue...'
    }
});
```

If `myField` already exists, that field will not be updated.

The caveat here would be that if you want to update other fields regardless of `myField` existing or not, you'd need to do that in a separate update query.